# Excel VBA if cell color is enter manually, then make next cell true

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need help with a VBA code based on a cell that's colored manually.
Basically, if the cell is green, then make another cell to say "True", if it's not colored, then "False"
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM0AC.png)

Thank you !

Comment: Look into `cell.colorindex`?

Answer (score 0):

```
If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(X,X,X) Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = "True"
Else
   ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = "False"
End If
```

Set the RGB value to be whatever 'green' color you're currently using. You can loop through a range to set the values.